# Unable to create symbolic links on samba share when using SMB 2.0

Tags: ubuntu, samba, symbolic-link

Note that I initially found the following problem on a Synology DiskStation. To make sure I wasn't reporting a Synology-specific bug, I reproduced it on a Linux Server. My  question below is based on my Linux Server test.

I set up a Samba server with Samba version 4.3.11-Ubuntu on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, and created a share.

When I mount that share on another Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS client via Samba 2.0, I am able to add and remove files and create hard links from the client.

When I attempt to create a soft link, however, I get an "Operation not supported" error as follows:

```
#ln -s foo.txt foo.link
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'foo.link': Operation not supported
```

I am able to create soft links when I set the protocol to SMB 1.0. Unfortunately, that's not an option due to vulnerabilities in that version.

My internet searches indicate that symbolic links should be supported with SMB 2.0, but I just can't seem to get them to work. I found some posts indicating similar problems, but I didn't find a solution that worked, or an explanation.

Can anyone shed any light or suggest an approach?

Here's the output of smbstatus on my server:

```
Samba version 4.3.11-Ubuntu
PID     Username      Group         Machine            Protocol Version
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1317      smbuser       smbuser       10.160.9.226 (ipv4:10.160.9.226:53454) SMB2_02

Service      pid     machine       Connected at
-------------------------------------------------------
smbdata      1317   10.160.9.226  Thu Mar  1 14:04:53 2018
```

Here are the contents of my smb.conf file. Note that I also tried "wide links = yes" to no avail.

```
[global]
    follow symlinks=yes
    create mask=0744
    directory mask=0755
    wide links = no
    unix extensions = no
    min protocol=NT1
    security=user
    local master=no
    realm=*
    passdb backend=smbpasswd
    printing=cups
    max protocol=SMB3
    winbind enum users=yes
    load printers=yes
    workgroup=WORKGROUP

[smbdata]
        recycle bin admin only=no
        ftp disable modify=no
        ftp disable download=no
        write list=nobody,nobody
        browseable=yes
        mediaindex=no
        hide unreadable=no
        win share=yes
        enable recycle bin=no
        invalid users=nobody,nobody
        read list=nobody,nobody
        ftp disable list=no
        edit synoacl=yes
        valid users=smbuser
        writeable=yes
        guest ok=yes
        path=/share/smbdata
        skip smb perm=yes
        comment="Test share"
```